# The aspect ratio is always 1.0

Tags: java

This must be pretty basic Java question but I can't get why below program outputs 1.0:

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int width = 1920;
        int height = 1080;
        double ratio = width / height;
        System.out.println("Ratio: " + ratio + "");
    }
}
```

I expect no surprises.

Comment: `double width`... most probably. `int` divided by `int` is an...?

Comment: it's not like a _direct_ duplicate, but it's the same idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing integer division, and assigning the result to a `double`.  If you want floating point division, at least one of the arguments must be a floating point value (as @Eugene suggests).

Comment: Solves it. I'll accept this after 10 minutes.